# Make a new dataframe of duplicate characters for each level of a subsetted factor

Tags: r

I have a dataframe (df) of shared interactions among species i and j(e.g. A_B) in a column called "interact". Interactions are recorded from the corresponding plot and region from where the interactions were sampled. I want to find all SHARED interactions among plots within ONE region. So for each region subset, the output should return duplicate interactions occurring among plots within the region. The data appears as follows:

```
df<-

region     plot    interact
 1          104      A_B  
 1          105      B_C
 1          106      A_B
 1          107      C_D
 2          108      B_C
 2          109      B_C
 2          110      E_F
 2          111      B_C
 3          112      A_B
 3          113      A_B
```

I want the output to be a dataframe that shows only shared interactions among plots within a region. Unique interactions for each region will be removed. So the output for the above example appears as:

```
output

 region    interact
  1          A_B
  2          B_C
  3          A_B
```

I have tried a for loop

```
region<-NA
shared.interact<- NA

for (i in 1:length(unique(df$region)) {
region[i] <- unique(df$region)          
shared.interact[i]<- duplicated(df$interact)
}


data.frame(region, shared.interaction)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R method that uses a split-apply-combine methodology.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df[c("region", "interact")], df$region),
                      function(x) unique(x[duplicated(x$interact),])))
  region interact
1      1      A_B
2      2      B_C
3      3      A_B
```

split the subset data.frame on region, then apply a function that returns a data.frame with the unique set of observations that have a duplicate for eac of these regions. Finally, `rbind` these together with `do.call`.

---

In `data.table` this would be

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, unique(interact[duplicated(interact)]), by=region]
   region  V1
1:      1 A_B
2:      2 B_C
3:      3 A_B
```

**data**

```
df <-
structure(list(region = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L), plot = 104:113, interact = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("A_B", "B_C", "C_D", "E_F"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("region", 
"plot", "interact"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: Thank you. In less than an hour you were able to help me with a task that took me an entire morning to attempt to figure out. I appreciate your help. @Imo

Answer (score 0):

Using `dyplr` you could do:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(region) %>% 
  count(interact) %>% 
  filter(n > 1)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#> # Groups:   region [3]
#>   region interact     n
#>    <int>    <chr> <int>
#> 1      1      A_B     2
#> 2      2      B_C     3
#> 3      3      A_B     2
```

You group by `region`, count how often values occur in `interact` and keep those which appear more than once. You could get rid of the new column by adding `%>% select(-n)` at the end of the pipe.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)


df<-read.table(header=TRUE,text={"
region     plot    interacti
1          104      A_B  
1          105      B_C
1          106      A_B
1          107      C_D
2          108      B_C
2          109      B_C
2          110      E_F
2          111      B_C
3          112      A_B
3          113      A_B"})

dt <- data.table(dt)
```

sort the data by `region` and `interacti`

```
setkey(dt,region,interacti)
```

use only the required columns. search for duplicates and finally `unique`.

```
unique(dt[,.(region,interacti)][duplicated(region)&duplicated(interacti),])

#    region interacti
# 1:      1       A_B
# 2:      2       B_C
# 3:      3       A_B
```

Comment: Thank you for your time addressing this problem. You answer was helpful however it was one more step than the other solutions since my data was a dataframe. I appreciate how logical an clear the code is. Thank you @DJJ